# Spring Display image that was just uploaded by the user without restarting the server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i'm trying to create a function that let user upload his profile picture and then he can display it while posting or commenting , i'm using Spring mvc , Spring security , hibernate and tomcat 9.

when i add a picture that was recently uploaded into the project root path and try to display it in the website , i have to restart so that it can work .
i cant make the server restart every time someone uploads his profile picture to display it , is there anything like a listener that would immediately see that a picture was added in the root path and display it withen the

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/basic-profile-pic.jpeg">
```

i'm using spring java configuration classes 
and this is my configuration class for spring mvc

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages =     
{"spring.ahmed.mostafa.data","com.ahmed.mostafa.controllers"})
  public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("messages");
    return source;
}

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator= new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
}

@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getResolver() throws IOException {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(5242880);//5MB
    return resolver;
}
}
```

is it possible to upload it and display it without restarting in root
or better not to put it inside root path and change it somewhere else ,
and how to make it work either way

Thanks!

Comment: how are you uploading the image? Generally static assets will be picked up as soon as you add them, without any restart.

Comment: by using this in jsp file <form method="post" action="uploadFile?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> File name : <input type="text" name="name" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload"> </form>

and saving it using method in controller , save it in root path static / images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  It provides easy storage and retrieval of "content" be that images, videos, documents, etc

Add these dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add `@EnableFilesystemStores` and `@Import` annotations to `SpringWebConfig`:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages =     
     {"spring.ahmed.mostafa.data","com.ahmed.mostafa.controllers"})
    @EnableFilesystemStores("com.ahmed.mostafa.controllers")
    @Import(org.springframework.content.rest.config.RestConfiguration.class)
    public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

And the following beans:

```
    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
      try {
        return new File("/path/to/your/images/outside/webapp");
      } catch (IOException ioe) {}
      return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
      return new 
         FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Add the following Store:

```
    @StoreRestResource(path="profilePics")
    public interface ProfilePicStore extends Store<String> {
    }
```

Now when you start your application you will have a REST endpoint that allows you to store and retrieve profile pictures to `/path/to/your/images/outside/webapp`.  Assuming your web app is running on `localhost:8080`:

`curl -X POST -F file=@/path/to/local/pic.jpg http://localhost:8080/<contextPath>/profilePics/profile1.jpg`

Or:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profilePics/profile1.jpg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type ="file" name ="file">
    <input type ="submit" value ="submit">
</form:form>
```

will store the file in `/path/to/your/images/outside/webapp/profile1.jpg`.

And:

`curl http://localhost:8080/<contextPath>/profilePics/profile1.jpg`

Or:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profilePics/profile1.jpg">
```

will retrieve it again.  No restarts necessary.

There are a variety of different stores supported; filesystem, db, s3, gridfs.  Just swap out the `spring-content-fs` dependency for the one store you want to use.

Spring Content can also be combined with Spring Data to associate content with Entities.  I mention as it sounds like you are probably storing users in a database.  There is a getting started guide [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-fs-docs/).

Comment: Do i need to store using ProfilePicStore interface in order to access it again ? or can i just simply add what you said to my project and upload image using <input type="file"> then save it using my controller method using MultipartFile retrieve ?

Comment: and in here  return new File("/path/to/your/images"); , i should return the full path of my project ? like C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\{Spring Project}\webapp\static\images ? or something else

Comment: @AhmedMo Spring Content will see the `ProfilePicStore` and the `spring-content-fs` dependency and inject an implementation of this interface for you.  So you don't need to provide this yourself.  Because of the `@StoreRestResource` annotation it will also inject an @Controller implementation so you don't need to provide this either.   The path should an absolute path to where you want to put the uploaded images.  There is no need - and in fact I recommend - you put this outside of your web app.

Comment: thanks for replying fast , i'v tried what you just told me an made the interface and put it with controllers package and provided the absolute path to where the images should be saved  
     { <form action="/profilePics/profile1.jpg?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type ="file" name ="attachment">
    <input type ="submit" value ="submit">
</form> 
}
yet i get this error " The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: and i don't need a method to handle this action in the <form action = /profilepics> cuz idea tells me that it cant find that action handler

Comment: CSRF?  Is your UI a separate web app to your Profile Service?  Then you need to provide a `CrossOrigin` annotation on your Store to tell it to allow access to the UI as shown in our microservice example here: https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-docs/blob/master/spring-docs/src/main/java/com/github/paulcwarren/springdocs/stores/DocumentStore.java

Comment: No you dont need a conroller method to handle uploads.  Spring Content injects a @Controller based on your Store interface.  Meaning you dont need to write this yourself.  HTH

Comment: No they are all together , i did all the steps above , but still each time i try to press submit to upload the pic , it gives me the error i sent you above , i only use controller to go to the link where i can upload the pic , i choose the pick and press submit that error shows  with this link above : http://localhost:8080/profilePics/profile1.jpg?_csrf=d8ccd8a3-9fe6-467a-9921-056d2d3d2d44 , the uploading doesn't work like when i used a controller method to read and save the photo , btw im using Intellij idea to run the project

Comment: I wonder if the csrf query parameters are confusing the servlet dispatcher? These look odd/suspicious to me. If you have one big web app then why do you need these? Can you try without them? If that doesn't work then can you raise an issue here (github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content/issues/new).  Or our Gitter room here (https://gitter.im/spring-content/Lobby?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).  We should probably not discuss more details here on SO and it will be quicker to resolve there I think.

Comment: Okay i will post it in github , Thanks for helping so far @PaulWarren